# Installing ufw on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance without root

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

How can I install ufw on amazon vps without root access  . Im logining  as ubuntu@ip .  Im getting error:  "Please login as the user “ubuntu” rather than the user “root”." when trying to login as root . I read that I can open access to root. But, can I change setting of firewall without doing it ? I need to add if of my home laptop  to firewall . And when I trying to enable ufw also getting error "You need to be root"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to login as the `ubuntu` user, and then use the `sudo` command to execute specific tasks as `root`.

Comment: Thanks . It works . LOL I enabled firewall and forgot to add my ip before closing session . Now cant login =